# Is there any way to install cs50 C library on a Fedora 31 disto?

Tags: c, fedora, cs50

I 've recently enrolled for an online cs50 Harvard's certification. We work on pre-configured sandboxes which use cs50 C librady for it's developing purposes. I am trying to install the library on my homepc running fedora 31 x64 by following the official instructions [here](https://cs50.readthedocs.io/library/c/).

When i run the curl command, as described in the documentation, i get the following errors/warnings.

1. No match for argument: pygpgme
   Error: Unable to find a match: pygpgme
2. The yum-utils package could not be installed. This means you may not be able to install source RPMs 
   or use other yum features.

[image]

I thought it was an EPEL repository thing so i tried to find info to get with it's installation on my machine but then i came across with an article explaining that EPEL is not for Fedora.

Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Thank you,
Kostas.

Comment: Please don't post *pictures* of text. Just post the text itself, properly formatted. This makes your question more accessible to people use screen readers or other assistive devices, and it makes your question more discoverable via search engines.

Comment: (a) the script is buggy. It is not necessary to install `pygpgme`. RPM performs signature verification *by default*. Whoever wrote this doesn't know what they're doing. (b) Those are warnings, not errors. You can ignore them and continue on to install packages.